# Cannot find Accounts table when using jitterbit data loader

Tags: data-loader, account

I am using Jitterbit cloud data loader to sync a local MySQL database with my salesforce Objects. While most of the objects can be found, I am facing following issue. I would be grateful if i can be helped or guided about following issue:

While i can found most of the tables in jitterbit while making a query, i cannot find Accounts table. Strangely, no one is facing a similar issue and the only hint i could get from internet was to check my proxy setting which i did.

[image: Account table cannot be found]

I tried to check if accounts object in particular has any security check that prevents it to be viewed in Jitterbit, but nothing such was found.Has anyone faced a similar issue?Is there a work around?

Thank you

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Comment: yes, i just did, and it is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when you rename the objects. For example, in my developer org "Account" is renamed as "Company"

[image]

So, when I search for "Account", I get only the following objects

[image]

but when I search for "Company" I get the actual Account object listed as "Company"

[image]